# How to set multiple RPATH directories using CMake on MacOS

Tags: cmake, rpath

How do we set multiple RPATH directories on a target in CMake on MacOS?  On Linux, we can just use a colon-separated list:

```
set_target_properties(mytarget
    PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib:\$ORIGIN/../thirdparty/lib"
)
```

On MacOS, we can technically add a colon separated list and `otool -l` should show it, but these directories aren't searched:

```
set_target_properties(mytarget
    PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../lib:@loader_path/../thirdparty/lib"
)
```

Normally, if I were going to have multiple RPATH directories on MacOS, I'd send multiple linker flags, and these flags would show up separately with `otool -l`. Something like:

```
g++-mp-4.7 mytarget.cpp -o mytarget -Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../lib,-rpath,@loader_path/../thirdparty/lib
```

Which gives:

```
Load command 15
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @loader_path/../lib (offset 12)
Load command 16
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path @loader_path/../thirdparty/lib (offset 12)
```

How do I recreate this behavior with CMake?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INSTALL_RPATH.html), the paths should not be separated with colons, but with **semicolons**:

```
set_target_properties(mytarget
    PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../lib;@loader_path/../thirdparty/lib"
)
```

Or, using the command [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#cmake-language-lists) to let CMake deals with the separator:

```
set(MY_INSTALL_RPATH
    "@loader_path/../lib"
    "@loader_path/../thirdparty/lib"
)
set_target_properties(mytarget
    PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "${MY_INSTALL_RPATH}"
)
```

**EDIT:** (thanks Tsyvarev for the comment)

Or, using the command [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html), which accepts multivalue properties:

```
set_property(
    TARGET mytarget
    PROPERTY INSTALL_RPATH
    "@loader_path/../lib"
    "@loader_path/../thirdparty/lib"
)
```

Comment: .. or use `set_property(TARGET)` which accepts multivalue properties.

Comment: @wasthishelpful Worked like a charm. Thanks!