# How to set CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH with multiple directories?

Tags: cmake, linker, dynamic-library, rpath

On the question [CMAKE RPATH not working - could not find shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398238/cmake-rpath-not-working-could-not-find-shared-object-file) I see how to set `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` for a single path, but I need it for multiple paths. I tried these using but I did not worked:

```
SET( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/opt/my/lib;/other/lib" )
SET( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/opt/my/lib:/other/lib" )
```

On the question [How to set multiple RPATH directories using CMake on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146437/how-to-set-multiple-rpath-directories-using-cmake-on-macos) I see I can set multiple paths with semicolon `;` for a target, but I would like to set it for all targets instead of setting it for each one. Is there a equivalent of `set_target_properties` for all targets (including subprojects) ? For example:

```
set_target_properties(alltargets
    PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "/opt/my/lib;/other/lib"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snippet:

```
# note: macOS is APPLE and also UNIX !
if(APPLE)
  set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path;@loader_path/...")
elseif(UNIX)
  set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN:$ORIGIN/...")
endif()
```

Related CMake variable:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH.html

Related CMP:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0068.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0095.html

Answer (score 0):

After testing, it seems the first option using semicolons as separator is working `SET( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/opt/my/lib;/other/lib" )`. For reference, there is the cmake documentation, but I did not found this answer there: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

The thing I do not know about is how I can use something like `set_target_properties` for all my `alltargets` automatically.

Comment: You reference not a documentation but a **wiki**. The **documentation** for the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` is here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html. It explicitly tells that variable is interpreted as a **list** of paths, and it explicitly tells that the variable's setting affects on `INSTALL_RPATH` property for **all targets**. Documentation for [INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INSTALL_RPATH.html) tells "This property is initialized by the value of the variable CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH if it is set when a target is created."